# Referencing images in files directory from twig template

Tags: theming, 9

In a newly installed Drupal 9 site, I have images in the **sites/default/files/** directory which I am trying to use in my custom theme.
In my theme, I'm implementing a custom **entity-print--node--deal.html.twig** template which is where I am attempting to output one of the images using the it's path as src in an img tag.

That template is for PDF version of my *deal* node type to give users a bespoke and nice printing experience including text and properly laid out images.

My issue is the  tag is broken on the PDF. I confirmed the uri of the taget is accurate.

In addition, I tested if images can actually display on my PDF by using the URI of an image on the internet. I created another image using the external uri as src and it displayed successfully on my PDF.

My template code is below:

```
<div id='container'>

    <div id='content'>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it 
        to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
        It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
        and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>

    {% set imgUrl = url('<front>')['#markup'] ~ 'sites/default/files/TwitterHeaderPhoto.png' %}
        
    <br>
    <b>Url check:</b> {{ imgUrl }}
    <br>
    <br>

    <img src="{{ imgUrl }}"/>
    <img src='https://numberonebatfan.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/iron_bat_by_bosslogic-d79c8ae_405x600.jpg'/>

</div>
```

And here is an image showing the output including the problem:
[image]

I need help figuring this one out, please.

Comment: Rather peculiar way to get the base domain. Why not get that variable in preprocess? Did you test just typing that URL in directly? Is it possibly due to the itok parameter missing on the url?

Comment: @Kevin: I did try typing in the url directly but that also resulted in a broken image. I'm not aware of the itok parameter. I will look into that and preprocessing